# How can I make this loop works?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sage

I feel dum cuz I was trying to make a simple loop for a matrix to show differents solves and I couldn't fix the index of the array: (FOA I am using the Jupyter Notebook with SageMath 9.3)

```
A=random_matrix(ZZ,4,4)
k=srange(2,7)
show(k)
i=0
for i in k:
    show(A^k[i])
    show(k[i])
```

And I receive that:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
 
"The matrix"
 
4
 
"The matrix"
 
5
 
"The matrix"
 
6
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c50cd3e70a78> in <module>
      4 i=Integer(0)
      5 for i in k:
----> 6     show(A**k[i])
      7     show(k[i])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

### How can I print in the right order the k esponent 2,3,4,5,6?

Comment: `show(A**i)`, k is a list, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `show(i)` call, you'll see the value of `i` each time is:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

So `k[i]` is getting the third element of `k`, then the fourth, etc.  That's what you're seeing when you `show(k[i])`.  There's only five elements in the list, so when `i=5`, you'll get an `IndexError` as you've seen.

Instead, just use `i`:

```
A=random_matrix(ZZ,4,4)
k=srange(2,7)
show(k)
i=0
for i in k:
    show(A**i)
    show(i)
```